# Can't get location when build apk relase

Tags: android, android-studio, location, google-places-api, sha1

I am writing an first android application. My app include firebase api, google map api, google geolocation api. they have same api key. When i write app i test it on a smarphone(sony experia Z1 android sdk 19) and it run well. After that i build it to release-apk with a SHA release on google.console and then i copy the apk to 3 android smartphone, only the smartphone which i tested(sony Z1) get location, 2 orther smartphone(ss galaxy note 3 + ss galaxy edge 7) can't get location.In the sony Z1, i already unintall debug apk. Anything else like Firebase, map run well except location. Please help me! Here are my gradle, manifest, google api manager. Everyone can connect online to me in https://www.facebook.com/anhdatday

Here's my manifest

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="le.orlando.ThinkSame">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="le.orlando.ThinkSame.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name="le.orlando.ThinkSame.MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" />
        <activity android:name="le.orlando.ThinkSame.Main2Activity" />
        <activity android:name="le.orlando.ThinkSame.Main22Activity" />

        <!--
     ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
     App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        -->

        <activity android:name="le.orlando.ThinkSame.Main4Activity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my build.gradle

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "le.orlando.ThinkSame"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.4.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is my main activity java, it get longtitude, latitude and cityname, it run well on test-phone. When i uninstall debug version then copy release-apk and intall again it still get location well. But it doesn't run on 2 other phone.

```html
package le.orlando.ThinkSame;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    Button btn2,btnx,btnabout;
    EditText edtnn;

    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    String city;
    double la, lo;
    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> user = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btnx = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonX);
        btnabout =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonaboutme);
        edtnn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNichName);

        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

        SharedPreferences userDetails = getSharedPreferences("data", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String test1 = userDetails.getString("nickname", "");
        if (test1.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "insert your Nickname", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Intent mh2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(mh2);
        }

        btnabout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent mhf = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main4Activity.class);
                startActivity(mhf);
            }
        });

        btnx.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        edtnn.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        edtnn.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            btnx.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
        btnx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                edtnn.getText().clear();
            }
        });
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!edtnn.getText().toString().equals("")) {

                    SharedPreferences userDetails = getSharedPreferences("data", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = userDetails.edit();
                    edit.clear();
                    edit.putString("nickname", edtnn.getText().toString().trim());
                    edit.putString("thanhpho", city);
                    edit.commit();

                    Intent mh2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                    startActivity(mh2);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please insert your nickname !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            la = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            lo = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
            geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this);
            try {
                user = geocoder.getFromLocation(la, lo, 1);
                city = user.get(0).getLocality();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed( ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        try {
            // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, connectionResult.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    }


}
```

One more thing, My project, when i find way to rename it i don't see any SHA in cliking gradle -> tasks-> android ->signingReport. So is it problem ?

[image]

here is my google api manager

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40295035/cant-get-location-on-app-release-apk

Comment: If your other two phones are running Android M or above, you'll need to implement runtime permissions.

Comment: So can you guide me fix the java code ?